# f# slow compilation

Tags: performance, compilation, f#, fsharpcodeprovider

Is there anything I can do to make f# code compile faster apart from (or better yet instead of) running ngen?

And what is approximate benchmark "hello world" compilation time (or better said compiler startup time+compilation time) for say pentium 4 machine?

**Edit** There are nuances as it turns out:)

So first, can anyone explain what is start-up time of compiler? And why is it slow.
Also links to information on the whole f# compilation process would be appreciated.

Context: f# compiler is repeatedly invoked on small snippets of code through

```
using (CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider())
{
  //start time
  cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, new string[] { data.Program });
  //end time
}
```

The time difference is ~6 sec. So the question basically is what can be done, apart from ngen? You can see for yourself here:[rundotnet](http://rextester.com/rundotnet)

Comment: Benchmarking compilation of "hello world" is *wrong*, you'll only measure startup overhead, not real compiler performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [f# compiling too slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697771/f-compiling-too-slow)

Comment: maybe this should be different topic, but what is startup, and if it is possible to "startup" once if I have to compile many times?

Comment: In particular, Chris Smith explains there why the F# compiler will probably never be as fast as the C# compiler

Comment: What do you find slow? Startup or actual compilation?

Comment: Which compiler do you mean? The F# compiler or the JIT compiler?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer Not sure, I just invoke f# compiler through Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider and the whole thing is slow. I guess I should correct the question.

Comment: How slow is it (in lines/s)? Why are you using FSharpCodeProvider instead of fsc.exe? Can you post the code?

Comment: the code compiled dynamically from c#, that's why FSharpCodeProvider, I guess fsc.exe could be called from c# too, if this would be faster

Comment: Startup time: the time that goes from you hitting 'enter' on the command-line calling fsc.exe until the compiler actually starts reading the code to compile (this includes OS overheads, .NET startup, any fsc initializations, etc)

Comment: And I think if you measure the compilation of something trivial as "hello world", it would be something like 95% startup overhead and 5% actual compilation...

Comment: On my machine I find it very helpful to switch from "Balanced" to "High Performance" power plan. For the project I am working on, startup times are reduced by a factor of 2, and fsc.exe seems to be favorably affected as well. Not sure how it works: either the OS starts using more cores or does not throttle CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This takes 0.9s on my computer (AMD Athlon 64 X2 4600):

```
#r "FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom"

open System.Reflection
open System.CodeDom.Compiler
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom

let comp() =
    use provider = new FSharpCodeProvider() 
    let code = "module pp\n printfn \"Hello world\""
    let cp = new CompilerParameters() 
    cp.GenerateInMemory <- true 
    provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, [|code|]) |> ignore
#time
comp()
```

Comment: @CheckMate9500 : have you run ngen? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697771/f-compiling-too-slow

Comment: @CheckMate9500 : that doesn't sound so unreasonable for a netbook probably running an Atom CPU... the F# compiler is very CPU-demanding.

Comment: A bit late to the party...yeah...but the Haskell GHC/GHCI is order of magnitudes faster...perhaps not a fair comparison but still... :-(